# Why did Supergirl kiss Nightwing in this panel?

Tags: story-identification, dc, comics

This is likely a scan from after 2005 (given Supergirl's outfit), but I don't know if it was from an **Outsiders** comic, *Teen Titans* or some other story. If anyone has any idea, I would be curious as to what caused Supergirl to just jump Nightwing that way.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be from Supergirl Vol 5 #3, from December 2005.

The [DC Comics Wikia](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Supergirl_Vol_5_3) has the following synopsis:

> Supergirl is combat training with Grace, Thunder and Arsenal wearing a pair of Kryptonite-infused handcuffs until Nightwing arrives and puts an end to the training. Supergirl is smitten with Nightwing and barely hears him as he tells her that Starfire has a lead on who's been tracking her.
>
> Three days ago, Starfire told her the Outsiders had looked into and found out who was spying on her: Lex Luthor. Kara was staying at their base while the team tracked Luthor down. Finally Starfire has located him in Monument Valley, Utah.
>
> Kara is ready to take off right now, feeling she has to confront Luthor alone. Nightwing tries to dissuade her, but she impulsively plants a quick kiss on his lips and flies off towards Monument Valley.

which includes what looks like context for the kiss (she already had a crush on him, and his protective "don't confront Luthor alone" inspired a "That's sweet" and a kiss).

You can see another page of it (from https://www.comicartfans.com/gallerypiece.asp?piece=1085167, which also includes a finished version of the page))

[image]

And you can see the designs for the other characters look much the same (particularly Grace's hairstyle which was one that struck me as not one I'd ever seen her in, although she may have had it for a short period while I wasn't following her).

It's remotely possible it's from another issue but I'm guessing she's only kissed him once.